# Is it forbidden to watch ballet?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty

I understand that the way women dress in ballet dances would certainly be considered indecent exposure, or not tznius, but if the context is not meant to evoke lust but beauty, is the exposure of extra skin still ossur?

Comment: Reminds me of the "photography clubs" of the fifties, when one certain subject of this art was far more popular than all the others.

Comment: *Lichorah* this is *assur* because of *al tismach yisrael el gil be'amim*. I.e. sure you could *taanah* it is culture, not *prosstkeit*, but the culture itself is *assur*.

Comment: Thank you! Toda rabbah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Talmud ([Avoda Zara 20a](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=20&format=pdf)) prohibits intentionally gazing at any woman; even if the gazing is only in order to appreciate her beauty.

This is codified in the Ramabam (Issurei Bi'ah 21:2):

> והמסתכל אפילו באצבע קטנה של אשה ונתכוון להנות כמי שנסתכל במקום התורף
>
> Someone who gazes at even a woman's small finger, and intends to
> derive pleasure from it, is considered as if he had gazed at her
> genital area.

The same language is also codified in the Shulchan Aruch (EH 21:1).

Comment: Notably though the prohibition doesn't apply to most people

Comment: @DoubleAA "The prohibition doesn't apply to most people"??? What are you talking about?

Comment: Is "appreciate her beauty" the same thing as "intends to derive pleasure"?

Comment: @Alex There are "pleasures of appreciation".

Comment: IsraelReader @DoubleAA is referring to the slight majority of the population which is female.

Comment: See also in [Berakhot 24a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.24a.15)